# Why is RestSharp returning text/html instead of json?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm trying to build micro service with TMDB API.

[image: IApiClient]

Code:

```
using System.Text.Json;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Net5Micro.Config;
using RestSharp;

namespace Net5Micro.Services
{
    public class ApiClient : IApiClient
    {
        private readonly ServiceSettings _settings;
        
        public ApiClient(IOptions<ServiceSettings> settings)
        {
            _settings = settings.Value;
        }
        
        public Movie GetById(string id)
        {
            //Init rest client
            var client = new RestClient($"{_settings.TMDBhost}/movie/{id}");
            
            //Init rest request
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

            //Add Request params
            request.AddParameter("api_key", _settings.ApiKey, ParameterType.GetOrPost);

            //Calling Api 
            var response = client.Get(request);
            
            var movies = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Movie>(response.Content);
            
            return movies;
        }

        // Za najpopularnije
        public Movies Discover(string sort)
        {
            //Init rest client
            var client = new RestClient($"{_settings.TMDBhost}/discover/movie/");
            
            //Init rest request
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
            
            //Add Request params
            request.AddParameter("api_key", _settings.ApiKey, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            request.AddParameter("sort_by", sort, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            
            //Calling Api 
            var response = client.Get(request);
            
            var movies = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Movies>(response.Content);
            
            return movies;
        }
        
        public record Movie(int id, string original_title, string poster_path);
        public record Movies(int page, Movie[] results);
    }
}
```

[image: Controller]

`GetById()` works fine, but `Discover()` throws an error. On debugging I discovered the value returned is `text/html` instead of json; I think that's the problem.

[image: response value]

And here is the error

> Exception has occurred: CLR/System.Text.Json.JsonException
>
> An exception of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonException' occurred in System.Text.Json.dll but was not handled in user code: 'The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.'
>
> Inner exceptions found, see $exception in variables window for more details.
>
> Innermost exception
> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException : The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
>
> at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader& json, ExceptionResource resource, Byte nextByte, ReadOnlySpan`1 bytes)   at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& reader, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state))

I'm new to .NET so I don't know how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It returns a HTTP 301 Moved Permanently. Maybe you should follow that move response and access a different URL instead. Get it from the [location header as defined in RFC2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2).

Your code is missing error handling. It probably should process the response only in case of HTTP 200 OK. Parsing JSON from a HTTP 401 Forbidden does probably not make sense either.

Comment: Thanks a lot i followed URL and found a bit diffrent one that returns application/json.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things that you can try ...

1. Make sure the URL you're using is correct, e.g., remove trailing slash.
2. Is the returned value really json for an object :`Movies`?  OR is it a `List<Movie>`?  i.e., { json of an object } vs. [ json of a list of objects ]
3. You want the 'Accept' header to be 'application/json' not the content type,  but since your `GET` example works, I really think it's #1 or #2.

Try this:

```cs
        public Movies Discover(string sort)
        {
            //Init rest client
            var client = new RestClient($"{_settings.TMDBhost}/discover/movie"); // no trailing slash
            
            //Init rest request
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            //request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json; // not required
            
            //Add Request params
            request.AddParameter("api_key", _settings.ApiKey, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            request.AddParameter("sort_by", sort, ParameterType.GetOrPost);
            
            //Calling Api - can deserialize directly to your Movies var.
            var movies = client.GetAsync<Movies>(request).Result;
            // #2 - might be a list that you get back? if so .. something like this:
            // var mlist = client.GetAsync<List<Movie>>(request).Result;
            // var movies = new Movies(); // add your mlist as needed to movies.                        
            return movies;
        }
```

You can also try testing the .../movie endpoint in Postman to see what is actually returned.